# Как подключить браузерные WebSocket через прокси?

Tags: javascript, frontend, websocket, proxy

Как подключить браузерный WebSocket, используя IP-адрес прокси?

Comment: nginx в качестве прокси используете?

Comment: Ключевое слово: **браузерный** WebSocket

Comment: Нужно, чтобы именно в браузере

Comment: Всё равно должен быть вебсокет сервер

Comment: Допустим, что сервер на nginx. Как подключить вебсокеты клиента через прокси к серверу? Нужно что-то на подобии http/https-proxy-agent, но для веб-браузера